# How to install curl without removing kodi?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, curl

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

When I run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install curl
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kodi-inputstream-adaptive kodi-inputstream-rtmp kodi-peripheral-joystick libappindicator1 libavdevice-ffmpeg56 libavfilter-ffmpeg5 libavresample-ffmpeg2 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdio13 libcec4 libcrossguid1 libdbusmenu-gtk4
  libfdk-aac0 libfstrcmp0 libindicator7 liblircclient0 libluajit-5.1-2 libluajit-5.1-common libmicrohttpd10 libnfs8 libopencv-core2.4v5 libopencv-imgproc2.4v5 libp8-platform2 libshairplay0 libtbb2 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libva-drm1
  libva-x11-1 python-bluez python-cryptodome python-simplejson
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libafflib0v5 libcurl4 libxmlrpc-core-c3 rtorrent
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kodi kodi-x11 libcurl3 obs-studio
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  curl libcurl4
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libafflib0v5 libxmlrpc-core-c3 rtorrent
3 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 4 to remove and 19 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,170 kB of archives.
After this operation, 96.3 MB disk space will be freed.
```

I don't understand why it wants to remove `kodi` and install `rtorrent`.

How can I install `curl` without changing anything else about my current system? I don't care what version of `curl` I end up with, but don't want `kodi` changed.

edit: the output of `apt-cache policy libcurl3 libcurl4` is:

```
libcurl3:
  Installed: 7.58.0-2ubuntu2
  Candidate: 7.58.0-2ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 7.58.0-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcurl4:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.19
  Version table:
     7.58.0-2ubuntu3.19 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     7.58.0-2ubuntu3 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Edit2: the output of `apt-cache policy kodi`:

```
kodi:
  Installed: 2:18.4+git20190831.2224-final-0xenial
  Candidate: 2:18.4+git20190831.2224-final-0xenial
  Version table:
 *** 2:18.4+git20190831.2224-final-0xenial 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: the packages listed won't be removed. if you want to remove them, use `apt autoremove` with sudo. If you don't want to remove them, then don't run `apt autoremove`. Secondly, rtorrent will not be installed, it is being upgraded.

Comment: `apt-cache policy libcurl3 libcurl4` please and what is your Ubuntu release?

Comment: It seems kodi uses libcurl3, and the current curl uses libcurl4. `apt` thinks this causes a conflict, and I don't know if there is an easy solution to have kodi and curl side by side.

Comment: @nobody I've edited my question with that output. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.

Comment: @KushagraSrivastava Are you sure? Did you read all the output I quoted? It does say `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  kodi kodi-x11 libcurl3 obs-studio` in there.

Comment: @sudodus can I just install whatever version of `curl` it is that uses `libcurl3`, and how would I find that out?

Comment: @localhost, I'm afraid, that it is not that easy. One alternative is to install curl and let the installation remove kodi, and use curl. Next time you need kodi, remove curl and install kodi again. This is a bit awkward, but possible. Another method might be to create a virtual machine, for example using VirtualBox, install some Ubuntu flavour into the virtual machine, maybe the light-weight Lubuntu and have curl there, while you continue to have kodi in your main operating system. You can run the main system and the guest at the same time - Let's hope that someone [else] has a better idea ;-)

Comment: Please `apt-cache policy kodi` this is strange.

Comment: By the way, how are you intending to use curl? Is there an alternative, for example, could you use wget instead?

Comment: @nobody I've added the output of `apt-cache policy kodi` to my question.

Comment: @sudodus I'm trying to download video chunks from a streaming site. I am watching the `inspect`-`network` output in Firefox and it gives the option to `copy output for curl`. Eventually I'd like to make that site work in `yt-dlp`. I'll have a look if I can use something else. I'm also interested for the future just because I'd like to understand why it won't install what I'd like, and how to resolve it.

Comment: Not from default repository.

Comment: I agree with @nobody. In my 18.04.6, which is up to date, the default version of kodi would be `Candidate: 2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1`. Is it necessary for you to use that 'git-final-xenial' version of kodi? After all, you are running a newer LTS version, bionic, and a package from xenial can be expected to cause problems.

Comment: In the new LTS version of Ubuntu, 22,04, `curl` is available both via `apt` and `snap`. It is possible that the snap version of curl would not interfere with kodi in that version of Ubuntu. It is only a tip of what *might* work, I have not tested it.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, it was from the `kodi` ppa not being updated when I upgraded to bionic. I didn't realize that ppa's didn't auto-update as well. After changing the ppa to bionic and then upgrading `kodi`, I was able to have `libcurl4` and `kodi`. All good!

Comment: @localhost, thanks for sharing your solution :-)