# How to manually change ppa version?

Tags: package-management, ppa, kodi

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic).

While investigating another problem ([this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1417007/164030)), I've discovered that the `kodi` repository ppa I had installed has not automatically updated when I upgraded from Xenial to Bionic - it seems to still be using the Xenial repo.

I believe I originally installed `kodi` by following the instructions [here](https://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux#Adding_Team_Kodi_PPA_repository):

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt install kodi
```

The output of `apt-cache policy kodi`:

```
kodi:
  Installed: 2:18.4+git20190831.2224-final-0xenial
  Candidate: 2:18.4+git20190831.2224-final-0xenial
  Version table:
 *** 2:18.4+git20190831.2224-final-0xenial 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2:17.6+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

The output of `egrep -v '^#|^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep xbmc`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/team-xbmc-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

How can I safely change to the Bionic ppa for `kodi` without breaking my current `kodi` setup?

Edit: I have just noticed that there are a few other ppas that I have that are also still using Xenial, so it would be wonderful if I could also get a more generic answer on how to change other ppa's to bionic.

eg:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mythbuntu-ubuntu-0_28-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/0.28/ubuntu xenial main
```

Strangely, when I run `software-properties-gtk`, it seems the xbmc ppa is disabled?
[image: repo disabled]

Is there something that I could do, or should have done, to get the ppa's to auto-update as well when I do a distro version upgrade?

Comment: Open Software & Updates > Other software. Edit as you wish.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'm using kubuntu though, is there a way to do it from the command line?

Comment: Software & Updates exist in Kubuntu as well. Easy and simple to do. I don't understand why you want to follow the much harder route (and prone to errors).

Comment: @ChanganAuto see my edit, I added a screenshot of Software & Updates.

Comment: Yes, very normal after a release upgrade. So, again, edit it and re-enable it. Edits are 1. `bionic` instead of `xenial` (mandatory); 2. Delete the whole "disabled..." comment (optional) and lastly tick it to re-enable. This should be done after any release upgrade and some PPAs may need to be removed if they don't support the newer release or have been obsoleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All PPAs will always be disabled** during a release-upgrade. You cannot change that.

It's up to you to manually check and audit each PPA afterward:

- Is the software provided by this PPA still wanted?
- Have the packages provided by the PPA been superseded by other sources?
- Does this PPA provide packages that are compatible with the new release of Ubuntu?

**There is no automated tool** to answer these questions for you. You must investigate for yourself.

**You must manually re-enable** any PPAs you wish to keep with the new release of Ubuntu.

Folks who are using PPAs on LTS releases might consider looking at using the 6-month releases of Ubuntu instead. The 6-month releases are thoroughly tested and stable...and have newer software.